# Let $m^\ast(E)$ < ∞.If for every interval (a, b) we have that $b-a$=$m^\ast((a,b)∩E) + m^\ast((a,b) ∩ E^c)$ then $E$ is lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure, measurable-sets

Since we are considering only few one type if sets (i.e open intervals) ,  i don't know how to prove $m^\ast(A)$=$m^\ast((A∩E) + m^\ast(A∩ E^c)$ using only information that $b-a$=$m^\ast((a,b)∩E) + m^\ast((a,b) ∩ E^c)$.Is the question wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the assumption is saying that for any interval $I = (a,b)$ we have that $$m^*(I) = m^*(I \cap E) + m^*( I \cap E^c)$$

Sub additivity gives us that $ m^*(A) \leq m^*(A \cap E) + m^*( A \cap E^c)$ so we will prove the reverse inequality

By the definition of outer measure we can choose a covering of $A$ by open intervals $I_k$ such that $\bigcup_k I_k = O$ and

$$  m^*(A) + \epsilon >  \sum_k m^*(I_k)\\= \sum m^*(E \cap I_k)+ (E^c \cap I_k)   \\ 
    \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \  \ \ \geq m^*\big(\bigcup_k E \cap I_k \big) + m^*\big(\bigcup_k E^c \cap I_k \big) \\ = m^*(E \cap O ) + m^*(E^c \cap O ) \\ \  \ 
  \geq m^*(E \cap A) + m^*(E^c \cap A) $$

Comment: Thanks Dionel for answer .I will accept it as it solved my problem but  one thing i didn't got is $$  m^*(A) + \epsilon >  \sum_k m^*(I_k)$$ true for every $ε$ ?

Comment: For any $\epsilon$ there exists a covering $I_k$ for which the inequality is true.

Comment: The definition of outer measure (at least the definition I imagine you are using) is that $m^*(E) = inf\{ \sum_k l(I_k) | E \subset \cup I_k \}$

Comment: Thanks Dionel , i just revised the definition .I accepted your answer as it cleared all my doubts and solved my problem .